# Multiple .CSS Jquery lines

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm quite new to jquery, but managed to do some effects the designer wanted, take a look at this fiddle:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zg35N/1/)

So I would like the words to come to the front, change color and fade back to the background and change color again.

The .animate method i'm using now is not really smooth, I searched stackoverflow and found no good solution, i however found the reason why it's not working:  something with rendering and browser compatibility. Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645326/is-there-a-fluent-transition-possibility-for-animation-font-size-in-raphael-js)

I read something about the jquery .css method and started to try that out. Much smoother transition indeed. The only problem is that i can't seem to combine several styles so they will be animated one after another as i could do with the .animate method: as shown in the jfiddle above

```
var duration = 1400;
$('.dgrey').css({"-webkit-transform":"scale(2)","-webkit-transition-timing-function":"ease-in", "-webkit-transition-duration": duration + "ms", "color":"#E5352D"});
$('.dgrey').css({"-webkit-transform":"scale(0.5)","-webkit-transition-timing-function":"ease-in", "-webkit-transition-duration": duration + "ms", "color":"#DDDDDD"});
```

Does anyone have a resolution for this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are webkit transition-end events etc, but for what you're doing where you already have the duration, a simple timeout seems easier :

```
var duration = 1400;

function ani() {
     $('.dgrey').css({'animation here'});
     setTimeout(function() {
         $('.dgrey').css({next animation here});
         setTimeout(ani, duration);
     }, duration);
}

ani();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zg35N/3/)

Comment: this works nice, but now the animation is not looped infinitely. How to set that back up?

Comment: @BenRomijn - you create a recursion in the javascript. Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jQuery transit plugin: [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

Answer (score 0):

Iwill do something like that, for smooth transition:

**HTML**

```
<div id="x" >TEXT TO ANIMATE</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#x{
position:absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 200px;
color: #0000FF;
font-size: 40px;
}


@-webkit-keyframes pulse_animation {
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(2); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var duration = 2800;
$('#x').css({"-webkit-animation-duration": duration + "ms", "color":"#E5352D", "-webkit-animation-name": 'pulse_animation', "-webkit-animation-timing-function": "ease-in"});
```

[Fiddler View](http://jsfiddle.net/tXLdL/3/)